# camera is being crashed in nativescript for the latest version of android or above version 8. is there any solution for it

Tags: camera, nativescript

I am facing a problem, while am using Camera in native script. it is being crashed while I am taking a picture.
below is the code which I have tried.

function onTap(){

```
const options = {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    keepAspectRatio: false,
    saveToGallery: true
};

camera.requestPermissions().then(
    function success() {
        camera.takePicture(options)   
        .then(function (imageAsset) {
            console.log("Size: " + imageAsset.options.width + "x" + imageAsset.options.height);
            console.log("keepAspectRatio: " + imageAsset.options.keepAspectRatio);
            console.log("Photo saved in Photos/Gallery for Android or in Camera Roll for iOS");



        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
        });
    });
```

}

Comment: Post the error log from the crash...

Comment: Please update the error log if you are still having the issue.